# PyInstaller Failed to execute script while converting from .py to .exe

Tags: python, windows, pyinstaller, exe

I've been trying to convert a .py file to .exe which has some dependencies (.mp3 and .png files) that i've included while converting from .py to .exe with PyInstaller. The application runs completely fine on PyCharm and cmd venv,when activated. However when i try to run the .exe file i have this error: "Failed to execute script". I've tried everything on the internet but nothing seems to work  [image: MAHMOUDPROJECT is my application]

Comment: can you run `.\exe_name.exe` on the command line, and paste the output here

Comment: There is no output. I pasted the command you mentioned in order to open the .exe file but the same error popped up again. After i run the app from the cmd it just skips a line and leave one blank. PS sorry for my poor english

Comment: Make sure you’re building the exe with console=True, then run it from command line - edit the full command and spec file you’re using into your question

Comment: pyinstaller -w --add-data "./resources;./resources" MAHMOUDPROJECT.py

Comment: i found a solution. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently `-w` was causing a problem so i replaced it with `-c` and everything seems to be working normally now.